# Is it possible to sort based on an arthimatic operation in Ruby on rails active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to order records based on two columns Arthimatic operation.

Ex: I has table columns on which I has to do an arthimatic operation and sort based on its value.
Let the columns be `math, science and total`.And table name is `UserMark`.
Typically my query looks like this

```
UserMark.order('(math/total) desc')
```

This should order the UserMarks based on math/total operation.How could it be done in Ruby on rails?

Comment: You say "two columns" and then list three columns. What's wrong with `order('math/total desc')`?

Comment: That is to give indication of table containing many columns.but,i need operation over specific columns.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking. You can sort by any expression you want so what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two possibilities.

You can do sorting in Active Record query itself.

```
UserMark.select("math/total as percentage").order('percentage desc')
```

or

You can do it in ruby method (this method should be in your model).

```
def percentage
  self.math/self.total
end

def self.sort_by_percentage
  UserMark.all.sort_by(&:percentage).reverse
end
```

Comment: Thank you.And,Is there anyway to get math/total value as percentage.Into our existing records to use temporarily.I can sort using the above method.but cannot get divided value on percentage attribute in my records.

Comment: Are you sorting in Active record query or ruby method?

Comment: In Active record query.

Comment: Then, you can access the percentage attribute column in the object directly. For example, "usermark.percentage" #should give the actual percentage value.